# Don't get AngularJS and D3 to work - SVG Element is there but no chart is generated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

i'm trying to get angularjs and d3 to work with a simple donut chart. But all i get is an empty svg and i don't know why. The SVG gets created as an 200x200px element but there is no content. Maybe there is a problem with the json data. I hope that anybody can help me. Thank you.

this is my index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Stromverbrauch App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- SIDEBAR -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#"><b>Hauptmenü</b></a>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <a id="active" href="#aktuell">Aktueller Stromverbrauch</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tfh">Stromverbrauch letzte 24h</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Stromverbrauch letzte 7 Tage</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Stromverbrauch monatlich</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Nutzerforum</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Gerätevergleich</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Tipps & Tricks</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">FAQ</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- HEADER -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ihr Stromverbrauch</a>
                </div>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" id="user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <p class="navbar-text">Signed in as Mark Otto</p>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="subHeader">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="stars">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" id="oneStar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" id="twoStar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" id="threeStar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" id="fourStar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" id="fiveStar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>
                <p class="navbar-text" id="rating">Bewertung des aktuellen Stromverbrauchs:</p>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- PAGE CONTENT -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div ng-view></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <footer>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="footer-body">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">Aktuell</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Letzte Stunde</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Letzte 24h</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Letzte 7 Tage</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group" id="group2" role="group" aria-label="...">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">Geräte</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Räume</button>
                    </div>
                    <p class="navbar-text" id="textFooter">Wählen Sie die Raum- oder Geräteübersicht und einen Zeitraum:</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</footer>

<script src="lib/d3/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my ng-view content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<donut-chart data="donutData"></donut-chart>
</body>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

and this is my app.js

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/aktuell.html'
          })
          .when('/tfh', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/letzte24h.html'
          })
          .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
          });
}]);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $interval){
  $interval(function(){
    $http.get('donut-data-api.json').then(function(response){
      // your API would presumably be sending new data, not the same
      // data each time!
      var data = response.data
        .map(function(d){ return d * ( 1 - Math.random() / 10) });
      $scope.donutData = data;
    }, function(err){
      throw err;
    });
  }, 1000);
});

myApp.directive('donutChart', function(){
  function link(scope, el, attr){
    var color = d3.scale.category10();
    var width = 200;
    var height = 200;
    var min = Math.min(width, height);
    var svg = d3.select(el[0]).append('svg');
    var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null);
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(min / 2 * 0.9)
      .innerRadius(min / 2 * 0.5);
    svg.attr({width: width, height: height});
    // center the donut chart
    var g = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

    // add the <path>s for each arc slice
    var arcs = g.selectAll('path');
    scope.$watch('data', function(data){
      if(!data){ return; }
      arcs = arcs.data(pie(data));
      arcs.exit().remove();
      arcs.enter().append('path')
        .style('stroke', 'white')
        .attr('fill', function(d, i){ return color(i) });
      // update all the arcs (not just the ones that might have been added)
      arcs.attr('d', arc);
    }, true);
  }
  return {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { data: '=' }
  };
});
```

This is my repository if somebody wants to see all my files (hope it's allowed to post it here): https://github.com/DavidH1904/d3_webapp

Best regards

Comment: Why are you loading js/app.js in a script tag in your view? That's probably causing an error and resulting in the render never finishing? Can you create  a working example for us to take a look at using jsfiddle or something similar?

Comment: Thanks Ethan, i loaded it because i thought maybe it has to be loaded in the view additonaly. But this was a mistake. Unfortunately that is not the solution. Would this be okay as a working example?: https://rawgit.com/DavidH1904/d3_webapp/master/index.htm#/

Comment: A working example that someone answering can modify to verify their answer would be best. However, I think I see the problem. See below.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are adding arc paths incorrectly. Specifically, you need to call data() after a selectAll(). Try this?

```
arcs = arcs.selectAll('path').data(pie(data));
arcs.exit().remove();
arcs.enter().append('path')
        .style('stroke', 'white')
        .attr('fill', function(d, i){ return color(i) });
// update all the arcs (not just the ones that might have been added)
arcs.attr('d', arc);
```